# Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js'

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to install spika backend (node applicaton)
When I tried Start server in stand alone mode with the following command:
$ node src/server/main.js

I encountered this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.min.js'

Node version: v8.10.0
npm version: v3.5.2

Comment: What was the output of ‘npm install’ ? Try to rerun the command and put the output here.

Answer (score 2):

> Install **socket.io** and not *socket.io-client*

*socket.io-client* is the client side library, not server side. You have to link it in your HTML instead of including it in your node.js file. It is *socket.io* library actually that is to be included server side. Read more on How To Do [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Integrating-Socket-IO).

Comment: I understand what you have mentioned. But I have used this reference for Spika Backened: `https://github.com/cloverstudio/Spika/tree/master/web/src/server` which uses socket.io-client too 
Moreover, I have tried to install socket.io manually but encountered this:
> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
> npm WARN spika@0.0.1 No repository field.
> npm WARN spika@0.0.1 No license field.

Comment: Its code is more than 2 years old. Nobody has updated it. I doubt you should continue working on projects like those.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following in the terminal at the directory of your `package.json file`:

`npm i`

`npm i --save socket.io`

- `npm i` will install all the dependencies in your `package.json` file
- If this dependency is not there you need to install it with `npm i --save socket.io`